# Sort 'grouped' Firebase data in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, sorting, firebase-realtime-database

I managed to sort data in Swift using the .queryOrdered method when items are in the same hierarchical level using many of the solutions provided, for example I could sort by likes;

```
- ImageID01
    * ImageLikes = 1
- ImageID02
    * ImageLikes = 5
- ImageID03
    * ImageLikes = 8
```

With the code looking something like this:

```
    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "ImageLikes").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            print("child \(child)")
        }
    })
```

This gets a lot more complex when I want to sort images that are part of a 'group' or nested in separate parent nodes. In my specific case users can add more than one image at a time to a specific post, for example UserA can add 3 photos and UserB only 1 photo. So now sorting all those images based on their likes get more complicated and I would like some advice on how to proceed, below is an example of what my structure looks like;

```
 - PostID_001
     - ImageGroupID_01
        - ImageID_001
            - ImageLikes = 10
        - ImageID_002
            - ImageLikes = 2
        - ImageID_003
            - ImageLikes = 8
     - ImageGroupID_02
        - ImageID_004
            - ImageLikes = 12
```

The query should return something like (least to most likes);

```
1. ImageID_002 //2 Likes
2. ImageID_003 //8 Likes
3. ImageID_001 //10 Likes
4. ImageID_004 //12 Likes
```

How do I go about sorting images based on their likes in this case since I can't go one level deeper and I can't query from the main parent?

Comment: There is no such query. You will have to do this locally.

Comment: @TheTiger Locally with with an array? Any ideas on how I would create the array; would I; 1) get the data 2) place it in array and then 3) sort the array, or is there another solution?

Comment: Yes exactly what you mentioned. Get the data into array and sort it.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  To access the bottom child of the tree, from the parent node, you will need to do something like this:

```
var db : Firestore = Firestore.firestore()

db?.collection("yourCollectionName").getDocuments(completion: { (document, error) in 
     if let document = document, document.isEmpty == false {
          for item in document.documents {
                for (key, value) in item.data() {
                     //save data locally to sort it
                }
           }
      }
}
```

This is using Swift and Firebase's new database option Cloud Firestore.

Comment: I'm still using Realtime Database, will this work similar?